# Angular5 - Test a function that calls a http service inside

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I need to test this function.

When I click this function `getallproductcomponent()`, execute this service function `getallproductservice()` and return all products. Any idea please, how to test this?

```
  getallproductcomponent() {
    this.ws.getallproductservice().subscribe(
      item=> {
        this.item= item;
      }
    );
  }
```

Only  `getallproductservice` I testing like this code, but how to testing component.

```
it('testing',
    async(inject([ProductService], (service: ProductService) => {
        TestBed.get(MockBackend).connections.subscribe(
            (connection: MockConnection) => connection.mockRespond(new Response(
                new ResponseOptions({
                                    })
            ))
        );
        service.getallproductservice().subscribe(items => {
            expect(items[0].alarmdesc).toEqual('call');
        });
    })))
```

Comment: You have to mock/stub the `ws` service and it's `getallproductservice` method. Read this article in the [Angular official documentaion](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-a-dependency), which descrbes about testing a component with a dependency

Comment: Yes I know, but how to implement in component, and when I have a function that call a http service inside?

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way**

```
let ws: ServiceName;

//in beforeEach    
ws= TestBed.get(ServiceName);

it('save should work', () => {
     spyOn(ws, 'getallproductservice').and.returnValue(
        of({})
      );;
     component.getallproductcomponent();
     expect(ws.getallproductservice).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

**Testing observables**

```
import { marbles } from 'rxjs-marbles';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

it(
    'should return the search result',
     marbles(marble => {
         const expectedResult={ item: {//something to match the api}}
         spyOn(ws, 'getallproductservice').and.returnValue(
            of(expectedResult)
          );
        component.getallproductcomponent();
        expect(component.item).toEqual(expectedResult.item);
      })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried Easy way and the result is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

Comment: I tried your first way. I don't understand, I have 10 products in server, when I put this:   `expect(ws.getallproductservice).toEqual(100);` the result is: `Expected 0 to equal 100.`

Comment: You should mock the backend and in this case the service.

Comment: Please, I edit my post. I can testing only service function. How to implement this script and in component function. Thnx